# Cutom Routing in MVC Razor URlHelper.Action Path Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have Custom routing for my application as shown bellow

Application Name is **ValidationTest** and i do changed my default binding to following .
That works fine , But i do have some Actions in Controller class , and i do use urlHelper to Identify the Action Path and Controller path You can see that in the Bottom code , But after i changed the default routing it throws me exception While trying to read action from url helper , and i am new to mvc so please suggest me how to give the path to Controller and Action

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
         "MyRout",// Route name
         "RubinsApp/{CRM}/{id}",// URL with parameters
         new { 
             controller = "Render", 
             action = "RenderApp", 
             id = UrlParameter.Optional 
         } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

so my url is

```
http://localhost/ValidationTest/RubinsApp/crm/test
```

so

```
ValidationTest=Application Name
RubinsApp/CRM =Routing Para
test=id
```

and this works Fine 
My Problem is, I have an Ajax Action Call Where The Action URl was Defined Like Bellow
in cshtml

```
UrlHelper urm = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
var urlsMenu = urm.Action("BuildNavigationMenu", "Render").ToString(); //This Thorws Object null Error
```

Here

```
BuildNavigationMenu=Action Name
Render= Controller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom route you have removed the `{action}` token meaning that you can no longer specify any other action than the one defined by default which is `RenderApp`. That's why the `urlHelper.Action` method returns null.

The way you have defined your routes, in this application you could only ever execute a single action (`RenderApp`) on a single controller (`Render`). In your urlHelper.Action call you are attempting to invoke the `BuildNavigationMenu` action but obviously that's impossible as this action can never be reached.

So you will have to modify your `"RubinsApp/{CRM}/{id}"` route to include at least the `{action}` token somewhere. Or add another route definition after it.

And just a side-note about your code. If you are writing this inside a controller action you don't need to instantiate a new `UrlHelper`. The Controller class already has a `Url` property:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var urlsMenu = Url.Action("BuildNavigationMenu", "Render");
    ...
}
```

Comment: I Added  the Default Action of MVC too so That Works , Thanks